# Pass data to Jison parser

Tags: javascript, jison

Is there a way to pass data to Jison such that it can reference it during parsing?  As a starting case, let's say we're using the [`calculator.jison`](https://github.com/zaach/jison/blob/master/examples/calculator.jison) and want to pass it an object, say

```
var parser = new jison.Parser(bnf);
var data = `{m: 4, b: 2, x: 10};
parser.parse("m*x + b", data);
```

Here's the calculator.jison with a new case `VARIABLE  { $$ = data[text]; }` added, which resolves the variable using the data object provided:

```
%start expressions

%% /* language grammar */

expressions : e EOF { return $1; };

e
    : e '+' e
        {$$ = $1+$3;}
    | e '-' e
        {$$ = $1-$3;}
    | e '*' e
        {$$ = $1*$3;}
    | e '/' e
        {$$ = $1/$3;}
    | e '^' e
        {$$ = Math.pow($1, $3);}
    | e '!'
        {{
          $$ = (function fact (n) { return n==0 ? 1 : fact(n-1) * n })($1);
        }}
    | e '%'
        {$$ = $1/100;}
    | '-' e %prec UMINUS
        {$$ = -$2;}
    | '(' e ')'
        {$$ = $2;}
    | VARIABLE
        { $$ = data[text]; }
    | NUMBER
        {$$ = Number(yytext);}
    | E
        {$$ = Math.E;}
    | PI
        {$$ = Math.PI;}
    ;
```

Comment: Doh, now that I've written the question I can finally understand the docs.  Answered here  https://zaach.github.io/jison/docs/#sharing-scope

Answer (score 4):

`VARIABLE = { $$ = yy.data[text]; }`

```
var parser = new jison.Parser(bnf);
parser.yy = {data: {m: 4, b: 2, x: 10}};
parser.parse("m*x + b");
```